# Devāpi and Maru are over 5000 years old now. What have they been up to? (They become co-kings in the next Satya Yuga)

Tags: kali-yuga, time, kings, genealogy

What have Devāpi and Maru been doing in their over 5000 year long lives? Also, how did Devāpi get to have such a long lifespan?

Since they are both described as being the originator of the Kṣatriya in the next Satya Yuga, it seems to imply they have children together, either by the gender-swapping in the Kalki Purāṇa, or while both staying male like some of Mitra and Varuṇa's children. I think it's while they are both male, as that nicely fits fit the major theme throughout the future prophecies of revealing The First Human as Sarvavarṇyantaka and eventually Sāvarṇi, as it would end the Sūryavaṃśa and Candravaṃśa.

These only show their story before they were even longer-lived than their siblings and after the events of the Kalki Purāṇa begin, which leaves a massive stretch of time where they are unaccounted for.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/devapi
https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/maru

Comment: How did you conclude that there will be any gender swapping ? It is said that Devapi will establish lunar dynasty and maru will establish solar dynasty.  So yeah , two separate races of kshatriyas.

Comment: @Carmensandiego It seems that those two dynasties end as new Kṣatriya are not mentioned as either and both are claimed individually as the originator (remember the Sūryavaṃśa and Candravaṃśa are only in this Manvantara). Also, the gender-swapping happens very explicitly and early on in the Kalki Purāṇa. Kalki's first wife causes men to turn into women upon lusting for her (except Kalki) and Kalki has the same (or very similar) effect on women.